# Get app-engine's current instance id in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, gcloud-node

Is there any way to get the current instance id from **app-engine** in **node.js**?

I found solutions only for **java** and **python** but nothing for **node**.

Answer (score 0):

As there's no traditional App Engine runtime for nodejs, I'm assuming you're using Flexible Environment (AKA "Custom Runtimes"). In such a case, you can [read in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#metadata_server) that using the Compute Engine Metadata Server can provide the information you're looking for. Custom Runtime / Flex apps are actually running in a Docker container on a Compute Engine VM. The docs say:

> Each instance of your application can use the Compute Engine metadata
>   server to query information about the instance, including its host
>   name, external IP address, instance ID, custom metadata, and service
>   account information. App Engine does not allow you to set custom
>   metadata for each instance, but you can set project-wide custom
>   metadata and read it from your App Engine and Compute Engine
>   instances.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Node.js AWS SDK to do it as well, version 3 has async version built in but we use [version 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) so I rolled my own promise version to call it from our app which is using koa but would work equally well in express etc.

```js
const getInstanceId = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const meta = new AWS.MetadataService();
    meta.request('/latest/meta-data/instance-id', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Then you can call it in async code:

```
try {
  const results = await getInstanceId();
  logger.info('Instance details: ', results);
} catch (e) {
  logger.error('Error occurred', e);
}
```